# Creating a DataFrame from a list based on specific values in that list

Tags: python, pandas

I am helping my wife out with some work for her primary school.

I have an excel looking like this simplified:

```
              score
NameA
test1           10
test2           23
test4           15
NameB
test1           10
test3           17
NameC
etc. 

What I would (ultimately) want is:

           Test1.   Test2.   Test3.   Test4.   etc
NameA.       10       23      Nan       Nan
NameB        10       Nan.     17.      Nan
NameC       
etc
```

So far I have imported the Excel with with all columns cocatenated, thinking to make a list of lists for all test of a given pupil, but cannot get it to work.

Looking for inspiration so all suggestions are welcome.

Maarten

---

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

1.Re-structure your data in excel in this format:

```
   Names   test  score
0  NameA  test1     10
1  NameA  test2     23
2  NameA  test4     15
3  NameB  test1     10
4  NameB  test3     17
```

2.Then, a simple `unstack` command will go the magic.

```
df = df.set_index(['Names','test'])['score'].unstack(-1)
df.index.name = None
df.columns.name = None

print(df)
        test1  test2  test3  test4
NameA   10.0   23.0    NaN   15.0
NameB   10.0    NaN   17.0    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change reformat your df in `pandas`

```
df=df.reset_index()
df['New']=df.A.loc[df.score=='']

df.ffill().loc[df.score!=''].pivot('New','A','score')
Out[406]: 
A     test1 test2 test3 test4
New                          
NameA    10    23  None    15
NameB    10  None    17  None
```

Comment: The forward fill is a suggestion I had not considered...it works! When I do further Boolean masking (I grossly simplified the complexity) it complains about the NaN's, so end up going back and forth with Nan's and other values; I can, of course forward fill with some other value...coming to think of it. Or would you have any other suggestion?